# Touch IC TTP223 hangs at 5V after working

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, touch

I used a [TTP223](https://infusionsystems.com/support/TTP223.pdf) IC operating on 5 V. I use the touch IC output (when high) to turn on the LED and (when low) to dim the LED. The LED is operated by the external 5 V.  It uses only the touch IC output as a signal. I used a blue LED. What is the problem?

It works fine when turned on, but after several days the touch output hangs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ESD can be a latchup problem.

Place a thin film (tight) over the sensor, adjust shunt cap for sensitivity then retest.

Comment: I also try 30 PF shunt cap in parallel with Touch Input pin but sensitivity going down , any other Ideas? that helps to solve out the problem.

Comment: Eliminate caps for max sensitivity and use glass for lower capacitance.  But eliminate static discharge somehow.   Separate issues